# About Unity 3d map modeling(with blender)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a 3D game with unity.
I was thinking about how to make a game map (3d space), and I found a program called Blender,
and I made a map made of low-poly.

It looked very awesome inside the blender program,
but when I exported using the **.fbx** file, it was disappointing in the unity program.
(unlike the color that I saw blender)
Should I add special settings when importing fbx files in Unity or change the export file extention?
I might give up Blender.
Please recommend a free program to create a unity game space.
[image: In blender]

[image: In unity]

I'm not talking about the light texture effect in the blender,and the water reflection. It's because the colors are so different.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as my knowledge about Blender and Unity goes, those two programs doesnt have the same material setting. And thus, the render material in Blender(either Eevee or Cycles) cannot be used in Unity

Therefore you need to kinda redo the material in Unity again.

Comment: It's really all about lighting, shaders, materials, etc. As @Hikari mentioned, you have to redo the materials in Unity :(. Try some post-processing too. Unity looks quite lame in default settings but it's really impressive when done right. As for blender, I would recommend sticking with it coz it's awesome. You have tons of features and it's free. It has some issues with compatibility with Unity though but there are fixes and overall, It's pretty awesome.

Comment: Well, is there a modeling program that has a material system which is same as Unity? Okay if it's not free.